# Plots of prior and posterior distributions for different models

Tags: r, statistics, regression, distribution, bayesian

Consider the code shown below that displays graphically the prior and posterior of the Beta-Binomial Model using different parameters in the prior.

```
colors = c("red","blue","green","orange","purple")

n = 10
N = 10
theta = .2

x = rbinom(n,N,theta)
grid = seq(0,2,.01)


alpha = c(.5,5,1,2,2)
beta = c(.5,1,3,2,5)

plot(grid,grid,type="n",xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,4),xlab="",ylab="Prior Density",
     main="Prior Distributions", las=1)
for(i in 1:length(alpha)){
    prior = dbeta(grid,alpha[i],beta[i])
    lines(grid,prior,col=colors[i],lwd=2)
}

legend("topleft", legend=c("Beta(0.5,0.5)", "Beta(5,1)", "Beta(1,3)", "Beta(2,2)", "Beta(2,5)"),
       lwd=rep(2,5), col=colors, bty="n", ncol=3)

for(i in 1:length(alpha)){
    dev.new()
    plot(grid,grid,type="n",xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,10),xlab="",ylab="Density",xaxs="i",yaxs="i",
    main="Prior and Posterior Distribution")

    alpha.star = alpha[i] + sum(x)
    beta.star = beta[i] + n*N - sum(x)
    prior = dbeta(grid,alpha[i],beta[i])
    post = dbeta(grid,alpha.star,beta.star)

    lines(grid,post,lwd=2)
    lines(grid,prior,col=colors[i],lwd=2)
    legend("topright",c("Prior","Posterior"),col=c(colors[i],"black"),lwd=2)

}
```

Some of the plots

[image]

[image]

How to have similar codes to the one above for the Poisson-Gamma model and inverse chi squared-Normal model?

What I’ve tried for the Poisson-Gamma is first to change the `x=rpois(n,lambda)`, and to change Beta by Gamma because here the prior has Gamma distribution. For the inverse chi squared-Normal model, would be `x=rinvgamma(alpha,beta)`, here the prior and posterior both have Inverse Gamma distribution.

Where I am having more difficulties is in this part

```
alpha.star = alpha[i] + sum(x)
    beta.star = beta[i] + n*N - sum(x)
    prior = dbeta(grid,alpha[i],beta[i])
    post = dbeta(grid,alpha.star,beta.star)
```

I don’t know how to change it so that fits for this new model. I have the same issue for the inverse chi squared-Normal model.

Could someone please help?

I would really appreciate any help you're willing to provide.

Any suggestion in the code is welcome.

---

The code can be founded here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70661/how-does-the-beta-prior-affect-the-posterior-under-a-binomial-likelihood

Comment: You appear to be stuck on the math, not the programming, in which case this should be on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Either way, [Wikipedia has a nice table of conjugate distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions), that has analytic formulae for doing online updating of posterior distributions, which is what you are asking for (including the specific ones you mentioned).

Comment: @merv Thank you so much! it's indeed really nice results :)